# Socket Connection Timeout

Tags: java, sockets, networking, timeout

In the code below.

If the timout value is 0  (newSocket(Address, 7010, 0);
The wait time is "Total Time in MilliSeconds =1024" 
If the timout value is 1  (newSocket(Address, 7010, 1);
 The wait time is "Total Time in MilliSeconds =22"

Is there any default OS settings (Windows) which can reduce the waiting time for the timeout value '0'. Tried few registry entries `LmhostsTimeout`, `TcpTimedWaitDelay` with no success. Please help me in resolving this issue.

---

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestConnection
{
public static void main (String a[])
{
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
          try
          {
                  InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                  System.out.println("Host Address" + Address + " Port " + 7010);
                  newSocket(Address, 7010, 0);
      long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("SenthilTS1=" + (t2-t1));

    }catch (Exception e)
          {
     long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("Total Time in MilliSeconds =" + (t2-t1));
     //                e.printStackTrace();
          }
}

    /*package*/ static void initSocket(Socket sock) throws SocketException {
      try {
        sock.setTcpNoDelay(true);
      } catch (SocketException se) {
        try { sock.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        //CR283953. Differentiate that the exception is thrown while doing a
        //socket set operation.
        throw se;
      }
    }

      static  Socket newSocket(InetAddress address, int port,
                            int timeout) throws IOException
    {
      Socket sock = new Socket();
      initSocket(sock);
      InetSocketAddress ina = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
   System.out.println("******** SocketMuxer.newSocket before Socket.connect() call TimeStamp (ms)=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
   try{
    sock.connect(ina, timeout);
    System.out.println("******** SocketMuxer.newSocket after connect() SUCCESS call TimeStamp (ms)=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
   }catch (IOException e)
   {
    System.out.println("******** SocketMuxer.newSocket after connect() FAILED call TimeStamp (ms) =" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
   }
   return sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should maybe edit your title to not be all caps. And also, there are some code in your question not formatted as code.

Comment: You must rephrase your question in order to make your question clear enough. For example make these things clear; What's your concern here? What's your expectation? What's the result you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The default connection timeout varies per platform. It is around 55-75 seconds but it varies. On Windows it is controlled by a registry entry. Why do you want to change it? If you are writing the code, why can't you just always use a positive connect timeout?